# Qemu kvm virsh xml config for emulating PPC (PowerPC) guest VM on debian x86_64 host

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

When I try to save with virsh edit a qemu config with domain qemu (KVM not supported on x86_64 host when running PPC guest) and machine either g3beige or 40p (any other I can try?) with emulator qemu-system-ppc on Debian x86_64 host running QEMU 3.1.0 and libvirt 4.10

I get:

error: invalid argument: could not find capabilities for arch=ppc domaintype=qemu

But if I run:
virsh domcapabilities --emulatorbin /path/to/qemu-system-ppc --arch ppc

I do get a printout with various capabilities..